# How to determine elevation drop along stream with ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, hydrology, tools

I need to calculate(estimate) hydraulic head(elevation drop) along a single river stream in order to find potential site for small hydropower plant.

I have a DEM with 20m resolution and raster and vector format of the stream.

Can anybody help me how can I do that with ArcGIS tools or in some other way?

Answer (score 6):

If you have ArcGIS 10 and the 3D Analyst, you could use the ["Add Surface Information Tool"](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00q900000016000000). It populates the attribute table of the Polyline Feature Class/Shapefile with basic elevation and slope statistics.

Answer (score 3):

you can use the [Interpolate Shape tool](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgiSDEsktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Interpolate_Shape_%283D_Analyst%29) to interpolate the Z values into the streams.

Once you have all the z-aware feature class, you can then add 4 fields, one for x, one for Y & one for the Z coordinate.
Use calculate Geometry to populate these values.

You can get the Z values that way. You can even graph these values, so as to get a visual profile. For this, I would suggest that you add one more field called distance, and populate it using the field calculator as (X^2 +Y^2)^0.5. You can plot Z values v/s Distance to get a nice looking profile.

Answer (score 0):

Stack Profile

Creates a table and optional graph denoting the profile of line features over one or more multipatch, raster, TIN, or terrain surfaces (ArcGIS Help, 2015).