# Elevation Drop Along a Stream

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, spatial-analyst

In reference to [How to determine elevation drop along stream with ArcGIS Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/15805/how-to-determine-elevation-drop-along-a-stream-with-arcgis), suppose I want to cut the stream every 100 m and find the elevation drop every 100 m. How can I do this?

Answer (score 5):

1. use Split tool in Editor toolbar and Split the line based on 100 meters (use "into equal parts ")
2. Create points from vertices : use "Feature Vertices To Points" tool (ArcToolboxb=> Data Management Tools => Features => Feature Vertices To Points)
3. Extract the Point Elevation: Use "Extract Values To Points" tool  (ArcToolbox => Spatial Analysis)

Comment: There are lots of options in the split tool. When I try to put 100 the "ok" button fades away.

Comment: I think you don't have license to use Interoprability Extension

Comment: If you have Xtools pro , you can use "Split Polylines"